# SphinxQL wildcard

Tags: java, sphinx, wildcard

I want to use sphinx in my project.And I would like to use RT index and sphinxQL.But I can't use the wildcard query.Does anybody have suggestions?

Here is my sphinx.conf :
index testrt

```
{
    type                    = rt
    path                    = /usr/local/sphinx/var/data/testrt
    charset_type            = utf-8
    min_infix_len           = 1
    enable_star             = 1
    rt_field                = name
    rt_attr_string          = game
```

}

```
INSERT:
insert into testrt values(1,'sphinx','sphinx');
```

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

```
mysql> select * from testrt;
```

+------+--------+--------+
| id   | weight | game   |
+------+--------+--------+
|    1 |      1 | sphinx |
+------+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

```
mysql> select * from testrt where match('sphinx');
```

+------+--------+--------+
| id   | weight | game   |
+------+--------+--------+
|    1 |   1500 | sphinx |
+------+--------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

```
 mysql> select * from testrt where match('sphin*');
```

Empty set (0.00 sec)

```
 mysql> select * from testrt where match('sphin\\*');
```

Empty set (0.02 sec)

I hope you can do me a favor.Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `%` instead of `*`?

Comment: Sphinx uses * as wildcard. Mysql LIKE uses %

Answer (score 0):

Need dict=keywords for prefix matching to work on rt indexes.

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.4/conf-dict.html

Note it is only prefix search supported right now, infix not functional on rt indexes